How do you unit test desktop styles applied using the "Object Syntax" responsive styles in Chakra UI?
I currently have a React project that utilizes Chakra-UI for styling and React-Testing-Library/Jest for testing.
I have a component that takes a number of mobile and desktop props which get applied as mobile and desktop styles respectively using the ChakraUI Responsive Styles Object Syntax.
I'm attempting to write unit tests that say "given these props, then on mobile viewports, it should have the mobile styles and desktop viewports it should have the desktop styles" but the unit test fails because the virtual rendering doesn't ever render the desktop version of the component. Normally, you can achieve something like this by mocking window.innerWidth to match your mobile and desktop viewports but doing so doesn't seem to trigger the chakra desktop styles to take effect. The component itself renders the correct styles on mobile and desktop but not in the testing environment. I suspect that this has something to do with the mechanism Chakra UI is using behind the scenes with this responsive object syntax not relying on window width and a resize event but I'm not sure. Here is a simplified example of the code:
React Component:
const IrbFlexLayout: React.FC<IrbFlexLayoutProps> = function ({
    children,
    desktopBackgroundColor,
    desktopColor,
    mobileBackgroundColor,
    mobileColor
}) {
    return (
        <Flex
            backgroundColor={{base: mobileBackgroundColor, md: desktopBackgroundColor}}
            color={{base: mobileColor, md: desktopColor}}
        >
            {children}
        </Flex>
    )
}

Unit Test that fails because it only ever gets the mobile styles:
import {renderWithProviders} from 'utils/test-utils'
import {fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react'

import IrbFlexLayout, {IrbFlexLayoutProps} from 'components/flex-layout/flexLayout.component'


/**
 * Mocks the viewport width for unit testing responsive design
 *
 * @param width - The viewport width number to mock
 */
const mockInnerWidth = function (width: number) {
    window.innerWidth = width
    fireEvent(window, new Event('resize'))
}

const allStyleProps = {
    desktopBackgroundColor: 'red',
    desktopColor: 'blue',
    mobileBackgroundColor: 'orange',
    mobileColor: 'purple',
} as IrbFlexLayoutProps

describe('IrbFlexLayoutComponent Tests', () => {
    it('renders the component in the document', async () => {
        // renderWithProviders has all of our context providers which includes the ChakraUI theme
        const {findByTestId} = renderWithProviders(<IrbFlexLayout {...allStyleProps} />)
        const component = await findByTestId('irb-flex-layout-component')

        expect(component).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
    // this works because styles defined in `base` render
    it('applies mobile styles based on screen width', async () => {
        // mobile viewport (meets `base` criteria)
        mockInnerWidth(767)
        const {findByTestId} = renderWithProviders(<IrbFlexLayout {...allStyleProps} />)
        const component = await findByTestId('irb-flex-layout-component')

        // Check for mobile styles
        expect(component).toHaveStyle(`background-color: ${allStyleProps.mobileBackgroundColor}`)
        expect(component).toHaveStyle(`color: ${allStyleProps.mobileColor}`)
    })
    // this fails because it renders with the mobile styles in the tests
    it('applies desktop styles based on screen width', async () => {
        // sets to. a desktop viewport (meets criteria of `md`)
        mockInnerWidth(768)
        const {findByTestId} = renderWithProviders(<IrbFlexLayout {...allStyleProps} />)
        const component = await findByTestId('irb-flex-layout-component')

        // Check for desktop styles
        expect(component).toHaveStyle(`background-color: ${allStyleProps.desktopBackgroundColor}`)
        expect(component).toHaveStyle(`color: ${allStyleProps.desktopColor}`)
    })
})


I found some others having this issue here, but the solution provided wasn't very clear to me. Also, I realize theres an argument that you really shouldn't be unit testing third-part libraries but at the same time, I want to be able to end-2-end test my component. Any help or insight to this would be greatly appreciated.
